# Can't remove trailing spaces

Tags: db2, trim, db2-luw

I'm trying to remove trailing spaces without success:

```
select trim(trailing ' ' from '1234                       '), '56' from sysibm.sysdummy1;
1                           2 
--------------------------- --
1234                        56
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is documented that trim will leave the data type as is - check out the [Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023198.html)

```
describe "select trim( '1234                       '), '56' from sysibm.sysdummy1"


 Column Information

 Number of columns: 2

 SQL type              Type length  Column name                     Name length
 --------------------  -----------  ------------------------------  -----------
 448   VARCHAR                  27  1                                         1
 448   VARCHAR                   2  2                                         1
```

If you want to change the look / data type of the result you can cast it to the length or data type you need

```
select varchar(trim( '1234                       '), 5), '56' from sysibm.sysdummy1"

1     2
----- --  
1234  56

1 record(s) selected.
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
select trim(trailing ' ' from '1234                       ')|| '56' from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Specifically:

```
select length(trim(trailing ' ' from '1234                       ')|| '56') from sysibm.sysdummy1;


1          
-----------
          6

  1 record(s) selected

.
```

Comment: It works by removing space between '1234' and '56' but still the resulting string has all the trailing spaces. My primary problem is not concatenate but to trim white space.

Comment: If you think about it, this answer proves that the trailing spaces were removed.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Perhaps you are assuming that they are there simply because the column is still being displayed with the original width.  Look again, the answer above is showing you that the length is 6, proving that there are no trailing blanks in the result.  The /column/ itself retains the original definition (see Michael's answer), but the /value/ in the column is only 6 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

Other method, if your db2 version enable RPAD function (V7R2 on iserie) :

```
select rpad('1234                       ', 5, ' '), '56' 
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```